# Setting the _id of cloudant in node-red to ensure order of documents

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloudant, node-red

I have a node-red code that works in the following way:

[image: First part]
It receives a message (json form) and saves it to cloudant DB

[image: Second part]
Then I can make an http call where I can see all the contents of the DB

This is all good, but the problem is that when it saves it to cloudant, it gives it a random _id, so the order of the documents in the DB isn't the same as the order they came in, but random.

Is there a way to maybe set the _id while saving in node red? Or is there another solution?

I just want that when I call the http it shows it in the order that it came in (last to first, or first to last, doesn't matter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `_id` with a *function* node or a *change* node before passing it to the *Cloudant* out node.

But if you just want them in the order they arrived then add the timestamp field and make the query node use a view that sorts the documents by the timestamp